# Trying to query for all objects with a foreign key reference to an entry with a certain value in one of its fields

Tags: python, django

The title might look a little confusing.  However, what I am trying to do is quite simple.  I have the following models:

```
class ListEntry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    expire_date = models.DateField('date of expiration')
    create_date = models.DateField('date created')

class ListWarning(models.Model):
    mailing_list = models.ForeignKey(ListEntry)
    first_warning = models.BooleanField()
    last_warning = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to query for a List Warning object that references a mailing list with a certain name.  Here's an example:

```
first_warning_list = ListWarning.objects.filter(mailing_list.name='PH_212', first_warning=True, last_warning=False)
```

However, for some reason, python is complaining of a syntax error:

```
first_warning_list = ListWarning.objects.filter(mailing_list.name='PH_212', first_warning=True, last_warning=False)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

What is the syntactically correct way to do this query?

Comment: Could you give the full traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double underscores rather than dot notation to refer to mailing_list name

```
first_warning_list = ListWarning.objects.filter(mailing_list__name='PH_212', first_warning=True, last_warning=False)
```

Docs [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships in lookups, taking care
>   of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind the scenes. To span a relationship, just 
>   use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores,
>   until you get to the field you want.